# How can I specialize low-level functions for performance while keeping high-level functions polymorphic?

Tags: performance, haskell, specialization

I extracted the following minimal example from my production project. My machine learning project is made up of a linear algebra library, a deep learning library, and an application.

The linear algebra library contains a module for matrices based on storable vectors:

```hs
module Matrix where

import Data.Vector.Storable hiding (sum)

data Matrix a = Matrix { rows :: Int, cols :: Int, items :: Vector a } deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

item :: Storable a => Int -> Int -> Matrix a -> a
item i j m = unsafeIndex (items m) $ i * cols m + j

multiply :: Storable a => Num a => Matrix a -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
multiply a b = Matrix (rows a) (cols b) $ generate (rows a * cols b) (f . flip divMod (cols b)) where
    f (i, j) = sum $ (\ k -> item i k a * item k j b) <$> [0 .. cols a - 1]
```

The deep learning library uses the linear algebra library to implement the forward pass through a deep neural network:

```hs
module Deep where

import Foreign.Storable
import Matrix

transform :: Storable a => Num a => [Matrix a] -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
transform layers batch = foldr multiply batch layers
```

And finally the application uses the deep learning library:

```hs
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as VS
import Test.Tasty.Bench
import Matrix
import Deep

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain [bmultiply] where
    bmultiply = bench "bmultiply" $ nf (items . transform layers) batch where
        m k l c = Matrix k l $ VS.replicate (k * l) c :: Matrix Double
        layers = m 256 256 <$> [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
        batch = m 256 100 0.4
```

I like the fact that the deep learning library and with some exceptions related to BLAS via FFI also the linear algebra library do not have to worry about concrete types like `Float` or `Double`. Unfortunately, this also means that unless specialization takes place, they use boxed values and performance is about 60x worse than it could be (959 ms instead of 16.7 ms).

The only way I have found to get good performance is to force either inlining or specialization throughout the entire call hierarchy via compiler pragmas. This is very annoying because the performance issue that fundamentally should be specific to the `multiply` function now "infects" the entire code base. Even very high-level functions using `multiply` via 5 levels of indirection and several intermediate libraries somehow have to "know" about technical specialization issues deep down.

In my actual production code, many more functions are affected than in this minimal example. Forgetting to annotate just a single one of these functions with the right compiler pragma immediately destroys the performance. Additionally, when developing a library, I have no way of knowing which types it will be used with, so specialization pragmas are not an option anyways.

This is particularly unfortunate because all the performance-critical tight loops are wholly contained within the `multiply` function. The function itself is only called a handful of times and it would not hurt performance if values were only unboxed dynamically whenever `multiply` is called. In the end, there is really no need for values to be specialized and unboxed inside the high-level machine learning functions. I feel like there should be a way to pass the request for specialization through to the low-level functions while keeping high- and intermediate-level functions polymorphic.

How is this problem typically solved in Haskell? If I develop a library that uses the vector package to generate blazingly-fast code in tight loops, how do I pass that performance on to users of my library without losing all polymorphism or forcing everything to be inlined?

Is there a way to pay the price for polymorphism (in the form of boxing) only within the high-level functions and specialize and unbox only at the boundary to the functions that need it, rather than having specialization "infect" the entire call hierarchy?

Comment: Which pragma's are you using? I think adding `INLINABLE` to any function with a `Storable a =>` or `Num a =>` constraint should do the trick. I think there's no way around that for type classes, but you could also try using backpack as an alternative.

Comment: Adding either INLINE, INLINEABLE, or SPECIALIZE works, but is brittle and unreliable and forces adding these to just about every single function in the code base. I will look into backpack.

Comment: IMO this problem is an artifact of the common but misguided idea of using types like `Matrix` parameterized on the scalar type. It doesn't make a lot of sense, neither mathematically (what is, for example, `Matrix String` supposed to be?) nor implementation-wise. What makes a lot more sense is to use type classes based on those from [the vector-space package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space). Then you can implement instances _only_ for those types where it's efficient, but still get similar flexibility and type inference. Also you move away from the whole matlab-like mindset.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I see your point and I will look into adopting such a design, thank you. However, this is only one example and I have run into several others in my other projects using plain (but polymorphic) vectors to represent various things. It feels to me like this is a more fundamental issue that crops up in many places where it is not feasible or sensible to hide the type parameter of a data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you browse the source for, say, the `vector` package, you'll find that nearly every function has an `INLINABLE` or `INLINE` pragma, whether the function is part of the low-level, performance critical core or part of a high-level generic interface.  You'll see something similar if you look at `lens` or `hmatrix`, etc.

So, the short answer is: no, the only way to get good performance with your current design will be to infect the entire call hierarchy with pragmas.  The best way to avoid missing a pragma and tanking performance will be to have an exhaustive set of benchmarks that can detect performance regressions.

There are a few compiler flags that might be helpful.  The flag `-fexpose-all-unfoldings` makes sure that inlinable versions of all functions find their way into the interface files, while the flag `-fspecialise-aggressively` looks for any opportunity to specialize those functions.  Together, they are kind of like turning on `INLINE` for every function.  This probably isn't a good permanent solution, but it might be useful during development or as a sanity check to get some baseline performance numbers.